# Understanding a command

Tags: command-line

I didn't understand a code that i used it's as following

```
find . -type f -size 1033c ! -executable -exec file {} + | grep ASCII
```

i understood the first part about type and size but where can i fully understand the grep command and what is the following after the ! and what does it stand for
I'd appreciate any information about what to do where to start i m really passionate about this kind of things i have a lot of patience and time any help would be appreciated
Thanks in advance

Comment: `! -executable` means Not executable ---

Comment: `grep` helps you find text strings (in your case the text string `ASCII`) in a file or set of files or in this case in the output (that is piped `|`) from the previous command.

Comment: Here. Click [this link](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=find+.+-type+f+-size+1033c+%21+-executable+-exec+file+%7B%7D+%2B+%7C+grep+ASCII).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `man` to read the manual or "manpages" for most commands.

So if you want to learn more about `grep` and how to use it, open a terminal and run `man grep`.

Comment: is ! with the grep command and -exec file{}? can find them in man i searched but i don't seem to find them

Comment: @Fantasy_CriT,  No, `!` is only operating on `-executable`.

Answer (score 5):

The `find` command finds and lists files or folders with specified properties. In this case, they need to be a file (`-type f`), exactly 1033 bytes in size, and not an exectutable (`!` means *not*).

For each of these files, the command after `-exec` is executed. In this command, `{}` stands for the filename. You can run the command for every file. However, in this case, the `+` indicates that one single command is to be built from the filenames. So if the `find` command yields `mytext1.txt`, `mytext2.txt` and `mytext3.txt`, the resulting command would be

```
file mytext1.txt mytext2.txt mytext3.txt | grep ASCII
```

The `file` command determines the file type of the file, whether it is a text file, or a binary file, or an executable, etc. So the type of each of these is determined, and only the lines containing ASCII are returned by the `grep` command.

Please see `man find`, `man file` and `man grep` for an explanation of each of the commands in this oneliner.